# I'm reading from a spreadsheet and dumping into a SQL database. A column can have null values, how do make it pass that null?

Tags: c#, sql, google-sheets

The issue I run into is that I read a google sheet in my ReadEntries method. The data gets put into the values variable. This then gets passed to the UpdatingAU method and added to my database. The E column in the spreadsheet can have null values. However when I try to add it with the rest as DiedFirst = (string)row[4] I get yelled at that index is out range.

```
public static IList<IList<object>> ReadEntries(string sheet, string sheetID, SheetsService service)
{
    var range = $"{sheet}!A2:E121";
    var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(sheetID, range);
    var response = request.Execute();
    var values = response.Values;
    if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
    {
        return values;
    }
    
    return null;
}

public static void UpdatingAU(IList<IList<object>> foo)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("among_usDB")))
    {
        List<Player> player = new List<Player>();

        foreach (var row in foo)
        {
            player.Add(new Player { Timestamp = (string)row[0], Playing = (string)row[1], Imposters = (string)row[2], Winners = (string)row[3]});
        }

        connection.Execute("dbo.au_UpdateInsertUsers @Timestamp, @Playing, @Imposters, @Winners, @DiedFirst", player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowning Google Sheet Api, it seems that ending `null` value columns is not part of the response.

You could try this:

```
player.Add(new Player { Timestamp = (string)row[0], Playing = (string)row[1], Imposters = (string)row[2], Winners = (string)row[3], DiedFirst = row.length > 3 ? (string)row[4] : (string)null});
```

So for those rows where the E column value is present, `DiedFirst` will be set - else `null` (if the column in the database is nullable!).